# Getting error : vector iterator incompatible

Tags: c++

I am making a program for class that manages a Hotel.  I am able to successfully check-in a customer into a room.  But when I try to check-out a customer from a room, I get a run-time error: vector iterator incompatible.  I ran the debugger, and says the problem is in the condition statement of my while loop, but I cant figure out what the problem is (I think I used the debugger correctly). I tried looking at other post with this similar error but I was not able to find a solution. Can anyone help?

```
void Customer::removeRoomID(int rID)
{
    vector<int>::iterator iter;
    iter = roomsCheckedInto.begin();
    while(iter != roomsCheckedInto.end())   // <--DEBUGGER SAYS ERROR IN THIS LINE - ERROR: VECTOR ITERATOR INCOMPATIBLE
    {
        if(*iter==rID)
        {
            roomsCheckedInto.erase(iter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend the [Erase-Remove Idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::vector` iterators are invalidated once an `erase` operation has been performed.  [(See reference here)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/erase/)

Try changing your code to:

```
void Customer::removeRoomID(int rID)
{
   vector<int>::iterator iter;
   iter = roomsCheckedInto.begin();
   while(iter != roomsCheckedInto.end())   
   {
       if(*iter==rID)
       {
           // iter should now be set to the value
           // returned from the erase() method.
           iter = roomsCheckedInto.erase(iter);
       }
       else
       {
          ++iter;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved it. I didnt realize the ++iter had to go in the else {}.  Makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You are not advancing your iterator anywhere.

You need to do `++iter` at some point or your while loop will be endless.

Also don't forget `.erase` invalidates the iterator, so you can't simply advance after erase.
Do `iter = roomsCheckedInto.erase(iter);` in case of matching id.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have to increment iter somewhere, or you will never reach the end of roomsCheckedInto - that is you will have an infinite loop.

Secondly, erase invalidates iter.

Instead, replace your while loop with:

```
while(iter != roomsCheckedInto.end())
{
   if(*iter==rID) iter = roomsCheckedInto.erase(iter);
   ++iter;
}
```

Also, is this homework? If so, tag as such =)

Comment: Your loop is wrong. You decrement iter from the second to the end which will cause an error.